# Listening for event in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I feel like this should be really easy but I cannot get it to work. I am using [screenfull](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js) which is included in a theme I'm using to make the browser fullscreen. I am trying to hook into the fullscreenchange event to perform actions when the either in full screen mode or not. The documentation clearly states the following example for doing this:

```js
document.addEventListener(screenfull.raw.fullscreenchange, () => {
    console.log('Am I fullscreen? ' + (screenfull.isFullscreen ? 'Yes' : 'No'));
});
```

If I put this in my components ngOnInit method this outputs to the console as expected. But I know this is not the correct way to handle this situation in Angular so I have tried to implement it using the @HostListener decorator as follows:

```js
@HostListener('screenfull.raw.fullscreenchange')
onFullScreenToggle() {
    console.log('Angular - Am I fullscreen? ' + (screenfull.isFullscreen ? 'Yes' : 'No'));
};
```

But no matter what I try it never picks the event up. I'm really hoping I've missed something really obvious and if someone could point it out I would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Jesse said, first prefix with `document:` (or `window:` if needed),
but notice when you used:

```
document.addEventListener(screenfull.raw.fullscreenchange, () => { ... });
```

you sent `screenfull.raw.fullscreenchange` as the first string argument to `addEventListener`, so I'm guessing `screenfull.raw.fullscreenchange` is a string representing an event name, so I'd imagine appending it as follows might work:

```
@HostListener('document:' + screenfull.raw.fullscreenchange)
onFullScreenToggle() {
    console.log('Angular - Am I fullscreen? ' + (screenfull.isFullscreen ? 'Yes' : 'No'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@HostListener('document:screenfull.raw.fullscreenchange')
onFullScreenToggle() {
    console.log('Angular - Am I fullscreen? ' + (screenfull.isFullscreen ? 'Yes' : 'No'));
};
```

I'm not sure if HostListener will automatically pick up on another library's custom event but in general with HostListener if you want to subscribe to events from the `document` or `window` you need to prefix your event with either `document:` or `window:`.

If this doesn't work you might be forced to use the onInit approach or considering exposing the event through Observable.fromEvent.

Comment: Thanks Jesse, I have tried prefixing with both document and window but no joy.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is `screenfull.raw.fullscreenchange` in your first example where the event is working with addEventListener? I notice that it's not wrapped with quotes. Is it actually a variable?